# Strong law of large numbers --> convergence in L^{1}?!

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, ...$ be a sequence of iid and integrable random variables with $E[X_{1}] = \mu$. Show that
$$
\frac{1}{n} (X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+...+X_{n}) \to \mu  
$$
in $L^{1}$.

My thoughts so far:
Strong law of large numbers implies almost surely convergence.
So I still need to get from a.s. convergence to $L^{1}$ convergence. In my lectrure notes I have found two possible ways of doing so:

(a) If $\quad$ $X_{n} \to X \; a.s.$ $\quad$ and $\quad$ $E(|X_{n}|^{p}) \to E(|X|^{p})$ $\quad$ then $\quad$$X_{n} \to X$ in $L^{p}$.

(b) If $\quad$ $X_{n} \to X \;$  in prob.  $\quad$ and $\quad$ $\{X_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$  is UI $\quad$ then $\quad$$X_{n} \to X$ in $L^{1}$.

Which is more promising? I tried both but...it didnt really work out...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What didn't work with (b)?

Comment: Well i didnt really know how to show that the set of random variables is UI...

Comment: The iid hypothesis makes it trivial.  For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K$ such that the nice thing happens for all $X_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your help...I am new to this forum and quite new to probability theory...So for now please excuse me if I ask trivial questions...

Comment: I didn't mean to put you down: I just meant, this step is easy.  Are you OK with your original question? Did the duplicate existing question & answer satisfy you?